# Can't activate virtualenv as non root user

Tags: python, virtualenv, fabric, ubuntu-16.04

I can activate my virtualenv only as root user:

```
source myprojectenv/bin/activate
-sh: 80: source: not found

sudo su
root@ubuntu-serv:/home/user/project# source myprojectenv/bin/activate
(myprojectenv) root@ubuntu-serv:/home/user/project#
```

How can I fix it? I need it for Fabric deployment as non root user:

```
def production():
    env.host_string = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'
    env.user = 'username'
    path = "/home/username/project/project"
    cd("home/username/project")
    run("sudo source projectenv/bin/activate")
```

Comment: Perhaps you could start with this great answer on Stack Exchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116596

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following syntax to activate the virtualenv

`. myprojectenv/bin/activate`

the `sh` shell does not have the `source` command.

Comment: OP probably wants to change his shell to bash (or just exit out of the sh instance he got himself trapped in).